# Careers has the correct city name, but wrong country

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

The main page of SO Careers displays a list of jobs near Edmonton, but they were all located in Washington.

When I click on "more jobs", it takes me to a search page for Edmonton, KY rather than Edmonton, AB.

If the results are determined by geolocation, shouldn't it be looking at the state/province as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks, we've fixed this so that the search includes region (province) and country as well.